# How to make a pivot table by multiple unique ID numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table

I'm trying to break up a SQL table that needs to take a users name and find the unique user ID's from up to 4 systems.

The data is currently like this:

```
| Name | User_ID |
-----------------
|  A   |    10   |
|  A   |   110   |
|  A   |  1500   |
|  A   |   4     |
|  B   |   20    |
|  B   |   100   |
|  B   |   2     |
|  C   |   10    |
```

I need to pivot it around the user's name to look like this (the id's don't need to be in numerical order as the SYS#_ID for each doesn't matter):

```
| Name | SYS1_ID | SYS2_ID | SYS3_ID | SYS4_ID |
------------------------------------------------
|  A   |    4    |    10   |   110   |   1500  |
|  B   |    2    |    20   |   100   |   NULL  | 
|  C   |    10   |   NULL  |   NULL  |   NULL  |
```

This is the code I have tried on MySQL:

```
PIVOT(    
      COUNT(User_ID)
      FOR Name
      IN (SYS1_ID, SYS2_ID, SYS3_ID, SYS4_ID)
     )
AS  PivotedUsers
ORDER BY PivotedUsers.User_Name;
```

I'm unsure if PIVOT works on MySQL as I keep getting an error "PIVOT unknown". Is there a way to find the values that each user has and if they do not appear in the table already add them to the next column with a max of 4 values?

Comment: No pivot won't work in mysql. You should remove the SQL-Server tag as this is mysql specific.

Comment: Unless there are fixed number of ids, you should go for a stored procedure.

Comment: There can only be a max of 4 IDs (so 4 columns) per user. However not all users will have exactly 4 ID's some will have anywhere from 1-4 ID's.